# What is the meaning of "disinter dream"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The phrase "disinter dream" is in the introduction part of the book "The Alchemist" by Paulo Coelho. What is the meaning of it? Can it be "thinking deeply about our dreams"?

Quotes from book:

1. > If we have the courage to disinter dream, we are then faced by the second obstacle: love.
2. > Having disinterred our dream, having used the power of love to nurture it and spent many years living with scars, ...

Comment: Are those specific quotes from the book?

Comment: yes there are. i added some sentences. But i dont know it is ok for licensing.

Comment: Quoting from a book for the purpose of criticizing or understanding it is fair use in most places. I wanted to be sure that was an exact quote, rather than a paraphrase or an example you came up with on your own.

Comment: Ok i understand, they are exact quote from book.

Comment: I changed "Example sentences" title with "Quotes from book". you are right, it cause wrong meaning.

Comment: hkuleci, did you mean the literal meaning of the word? Because then this would be pretty likely to be closed as off-topic: answerable with a dictionary. Or the figurative sense?

Comment: There is a small problem with the first quotation. Standard English would use 'disinter [determiner] dream'  - probably 'disinter our dream', to match the second quotation. Coelho's own blog uses 'disinter dream', but the Merriam-Webster definition for 'disinter' includes the quotation as 'disinter our dream'.

Comment: @Stephie i dont know this phrase has a literal meaning or not. i try to understand, what does the author want to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm channeling my Latin here:

*[To inter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inter)* means burrying someone or something, literally *to put into the earth*, from *terra*, *earth*, (which lost an 'r' along the way).

The prefix *dis-* means *un-*.

So ***[to disinter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disinter)*** is ***to unbury*** or ***to unearth***.

These terms may be used in a literal sense as well as in a figurative sense - ***to think, talk or write about something that was previously hidden and ignored***.